# Read in a lot of elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, modularity, modular-design

I know JS basics, but I would like to take it the next step.

I would like to change CSS with the help of JS on a lot of elements. The problem is that the only method I know to select elements is the

```
const name = document.getElement...(id/class/tag etc.);
```

So I can later on refer to that element by its name and change its style by:

```
name.style.cssproperty = "something";
```

And this is okay, but when I have like 10 elements already, I feel it very inefficient to do it that way.

So my question is, Is there a better way to change CSS dynamically more efficiently, so the beginning of my code doesn't look like this:

```
const name = document.getElement...(id/class/tag etc.);
const name = document.getElement...(id/class/tag etc.);
const name = document.getElement...(id/class/tag etc.);
const name = document.getElement...(id/class/tag etc.);
const name = document.getElement...(id/class/tag etc.);
etc...
```

Or is it normal to have so many variables?

I hope my question can be understood.

PS:

I just started learning about Modular JavaScript! Is this any kind of help to my problem?

Comment: You probably want to use: arrays, objects, for-loops, and `document.querySelectorAll`. That all said, you also probably want to avoid modifying `style` as much as possible in favor of just toggling classes.

Comment: What is the nature of the css you're trying to change?  Is it all very similar transformations?  As @zzzzBov said the best way to do this is by using classes you made in your stylesheets.

Comment: For example, see this link on how to get multiple elements by class name and then filter the resulting array by arbitrary criteria https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all your elements by a given class:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('my-class');
```

Now you can loop through the fetched elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.cssproperty = "something";
}
```

Or if ES6+ is available in your environment:

```
elements.forEach(element => element.style.cssproperty = "something");
```